# Why are CSS rules not applied correctly on old Safari + Safari-like browsers

Tags: html, css, web, safari

I am making a website serving pure HTML and CSS to the client, for maximum compatibility.
This website is supposed to be responsive, and as such, was created and debugged using integrated developer consoles in my browser of choice. However, when opening it on some mobile devices (iPhone 6S+, iPhone X), or Safari (13), the CSS just doesn't apply properly.
(It seems to display properly on Safari on an iPhone XE(most recent version))

By "doesn't apply properly', i don't mean "is applied but does not yield the expected results". I mean that the client correctly downloads the page, CSS included, but refuses to apply some or all of it.

Simple example of a barebones page (Navbar + Footer)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar">
      <div id="overlay"></div>
      <button id="menu-toggle">MENU</button>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://localhost">SAMPLE</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">
      <h5 class="copyright">
          Corporation Corp
      </h5>
      <h5>
          <a>
              Informations légales
          </a>
      </h5>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$layout-switch: 13 / 16
$rpx: calc(0.8px + 0.05335vmin)

#navbar
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between

#navbar > ul
  list-style: none
  display: inline

  > li > a:active, a:hover, a:visited, a:link
    text-decoration: none
    color: black

#footer
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: nowrap
  flex-direction: row
  align-items: center
  justify-content: space-between

.copyright:before
  content: "©"

.hidden
  display: none


@media (max-aspect-ratio: $layout-switch)
  //Mobile

  #navbar > ul

    position: fixed
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    translate: -50% -50%
    padding-left: 0


    > li
      &:not(:last-of-type)
        margin-bottom: calc(20 * $rpx)



@media (min-aspect-ratio: $layout-switch)
  //Desktop

  #menu-toggle, #overlay
    display: none

  #navbar

    justify-content: space-between

    > ul
      > li
        display: inline

        &:not(:last-of-type)
          margin-right: 10px

        > a:active, a:hover, a:visited, a:link
          color: black
```

[image: Expected result (mobile)]
Expected mobile result

[image: Result on Safari(latest supported version) on an iPhone 6S+ running iOS 14.7]
Result on Safari mobile + Safari-like mobile browsers

[image: Expected result (desktop)]
Expected desktop result

[image: Result on Safari 13]
Result on Safari Desktop

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you have given as CSS (eg where are the {}) but basically some features are just not supported on older Safaris for example nesting. See caniuse.com to checkout compatibility.

Comment: Actually, i just figured this out, the problem was with the media queries (unsupported on old safari versions). Also, the nesting and absent brackets are because i use SASS (a CSS preprocessor)